# Different timezone in WebSSO using ADFS as IDP

Tags: sso, saml

Is there a best practise when it comes to handling timezones in an international single-sign-on solution?

I've been asked to include the clients timezone in our saml-ticket as an attribute. This will later be used to filter logs.

The only solution I can come up with is to create an custom login-page on the idp(ADFS in this case) and use javascript. This is what I call a "best effort-solution".

Has anyone worked with WebSSO and faced the same task as described above? What does the "websso-world" say about these kinds of "client-attributes"?

Comment: Do you get the cloent timezone from the browser request headers? In that case I would suggest retrieving the timezone in the application using the saml ticket instead. Is it a hard requrement for javing it in the saml ticket?